# Prime Matrix with determinant of powers $2^x$

Tags: function-construction, linear-algebra, prime-numbers

Mathematica has commands for finding prime matrices, for example, here is a matrix with randoms in the range $<100$:

```
RandomPrime[100, {3, 3}]
```

This $2 \times 2$ example has:

$$\begin{vmatrix}71&89\\17&79\end{vmatrix} = 2^{12}$$

This $3 \times 3$ example has:

$$\begin{vmatrix} 71 & 31 & 97 \\ 61 & 67 & 23 \\ 7 & 83 & 73 \end{vmatrix} = 2^{19}$$

I have been doing brute force based on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3749037/3-times-3-matrix-with-determinant-a-large-power-of-2), but that is just too slow.

Is there some quick way to search through random $3 \times 3$ determinant values (random primes less than $100$ and no duplicates) to discover a larger determinant than $2^{19}$ (note that we want the determinant to be a power of $2^x$).

I tried using [`Reduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html) and [`FindInstance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html) with the general determinants, but that did not produce useful results.

Comment: My apologies for not being clear - the determinant must be a power of $2^x$ (updated question to hopefully make that clearer). Do you have any ideas?

Comment: It's probably worth asking at Mathematics SE if there's an upper bound on a determinant with any positive integer entries $2\leq e_{ij}\leq97$. Most answers out there deal with -1,0,1 entries. Unfortunately there are `Binomial[25, 9] * 9! == 741354768000` possible determinants (`Prime[25]` is 97) which is too big to explore with brute force. I'd wager that the maximum cannot be more than `Prime[25]*2^12 + Prime[24]*2^12 + Prime[23]*2^12` as 2^12 is the highest 2x2 determinant, which puts it slightly above 2^20, so it's possible there is one out there.

Comment: ^ I should say 741354768000 possible matrices - the number of determinants is probably much smaller.

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1291083/matrix-with-prime-entries-and-largest-possible-determinant and https://oeis.org/A180128 if you constrain it to the first $n^2$ primes.

Comment: I was able to find a fully prime near-miss `{{71, 7, 89}, {83, 79, 2}, {3, 97, 73}}`. My Parallelepiped argument didn't work because I was being stupid - there are obviously parallelepipeds which exceed the cube's bounds!

Comment: @flinty: I really appreciate the effort and that was really close!